# How to get dependent files for ConTeXt file

Tags: compiling, context, latexmk

I would like to automatically compile a context .tex-file whenever any of the files that it depends on are modified, i.e. the behaviour of latexmk's continuous compilation (`latexmk -pvc`). I could kind of do this with a Makefile similar to this

```
test.pdf: test.tex
    context test

watch:
    while true; do make -q || make; sleep 0.5; done
```

which will run `context test` everytime test.tex is changed, but this becomes cumbersome when there are lots of dependencies such as using external code files for code listings and external images. So I would like to know if there is a way to get all external files used in a context .tex-file to be able to automate building the Makefile, or if there is another way to get the behaviour of `latexmk -pvc`.

Comment: Latexmk maintainer here: I don't know of any tool to do what you want. But I see that context reports at least some dependencies in its .log file, in what looks like a systematic format. So it **might** be straightforward to write a script (e.g. in Perl) to get the dependency information from the .log file. It would also be worth asking the authors of context.

Comment: You can search the log file for `open source` to get all the included source files.  For included images, I am sure there is some kind of tacker that you can enable to print these to the log as well.

Comment: Thank you both! `context --trackers=resolvers.readfile test.tex` seems to print what I want to the log file, will update my question when I have something that works well.

Comment: Slarwise, it's possible to use `inotifywait` in a bash script to rebuild the document. See my [blog post](https://dave.autonoma.ca/blog/2019/06/16/typesetting-markdown-part-3/#continuous-integration) on continuous integration for details.